# Unable to change <select> field more than once using Cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I'm new to using Cypress and just writing a few basic tests for our application to see it in action. However, I've encountered an issue that I haven't been able to resolve or locate a solution for yet; however, at first, glance appears to be relatively straightforward.

When navigating to a page, we have a few `select` fields a user can change, which will alter the text of a `div` depending on their selection. These fields are also saved `onChange` to our database, so when a user uses this object again, we can pre-populate the fields.

When the database is clear of any pre-selected options, the `select` will correctly be set to `European Union,`  and the dynamic text will be tested and confirmed.

```
cy.get('#jurisdiction').select('European Union', { force: true })

// Assertion to confirm preview
cy.get('.ilPreviewDiv').invoke('text').then((text) => text.trim()).should('equal', 'text1, text2, text3, text4.')
```

Afterward, the select will then correctly be switched to `United States`, the assertion for dynamic text will always fail. I've even attempted to extend the timeout; however, it doesn't appear to make a difference as it doesn't appear actually to wait as long as I set it too.

```
cy.get('#jurisdiction', { timeout: 15000 }).select('United States', { force: true })
      
// Assertion to confirm preview
cy.get('.ilPreviewDiv').invoke('text').then((text) => text.trim()).should('equal', 'text1, text2, text3.')
```

I'm unsure why this occurs as it seems simple enough, but I'm clearly doing something incorrectly. In addition to this, I've placed the `select` field code below.

```
<select name="jurisdiction" id="jurisdiction" class="" onchange="updateSelectedJurisdiction(33652); updateOptions(this);">
    <option value="">N/A</option>               
    <option value="United States">United States</option>                
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>              
    <option value="European Union" selected="">European Union</option>          
    <option value="US and CA">US and CA</option>            
    <option value="US and EU">US and EU</option>                
    <option value="US, CA, and EU">US, CA, and EU</option>      
</select>
```

In addition to this, if the database has `European Union` stored, the `.select('United States')` appears to be successful; however, the value in the `select` never changes, and therefore the dynamic text never updates, and the assertion fails.

Any assistance that could be provided would be greatly appreciated. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**Edit:**
As suggested, I tried adding `.trigger('change')` to the end of the `.select()` and instead now getting an error saying it failed because the element is detached from the DOM. A quick Google search seemed to suggest many others have had this problem, and despite trying to follow along, I've still been unsuccessful. It might be due more to my inexperience than anything but still stuck trying to resolve.

Comment: Perhaps adding `.trigger('change')` after the `.select()` will help. See [select - Command Log](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select.html#Command-Log) on how to see what events occurred.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I edited my post with the updated attempt, however now getting an error suggesting the element is disconnected from the DOM. Still trying to work through it, but aside from Cypress I'm a bit green in web development in general so could be more on me. I definitely appreciate the suggestion and will keep at it though!

Comment: Good on you for giving it a go, unfortunately `<select>` and events can be a bit sticky.

Comment: Looking at `onchange="updateSelectedJurisdiction(33652); updateOptions(this);"` I would say the change event is actually happening during the `.select('United States', { force: true })`, so `.trigger('change')` likely is not necessary. Can you confirm that there is a change event showing in the console, as per the example in [select - Command Log](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select.html#Command-Log) where they show MouseDown, MouseUp, and Click events - you should see a Change event recorded even without using `.trigger('change')`.

Comment: To fix "the element is detached from the DOM" simply add a cy.wait() before the command. It should fix the problem :)

Comment: Since trigger change shows error "the element is detached from the DOM" It is possible that you have triggered a page reload and you are in the scope of a within functions. If that is the case - exit that function and get the elements needed for validation outside of it, after you wait for some time.